# Will beginners books on ROS Indigo still be worthwhile when using Jade?

Tags: ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am planning on learning ROS from scratch, and consider my options on how to best get started. I found [this book tutorial](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/) which teaches ROS Indigo, which i think looks promising. However, I find it logical to learn ROS Jade, since it's out now, and I would mainly be using it for simulations with Gazebo.

Are the basics of Jade and Indigo similar enough that reading a book on Indigo will be practical when working with Jade?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217126/will-beginners-books-on-ros-indigo-still-be-worthwhile-when-using-jade?/) by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Are the basics of Jade and Indigo similar enough that reading a book on Indigo will be practical when working with Jade?

Yes.

In fact, Indigo and Jade are as far as I can see completely identical at that level (you can always check the [Jade migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration)). AGITR doesn't use any really complex components (such as navigation or MoveIt) which are more likely to change between ROS releases.

You'll have to replace `jade` wherever you read `indigo` (in paths, etc), but other than that you should be able to use the book without issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on 2015-09-06**:
Allright! That was what I was hoping for. Thanks!

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-09-06**:
You should also bear in mind that Indigo has long term support, so will be around as a supported version longer than Jade will be. Also depending on what robot/robots you use ROS with Indigo might make more sense as they may not have transitioned to Jade.

**Comment by [Tormod Haugene](https://answers.ros.org/users/23774/tormod-haugene/) on 2015-09-06**:
@nickw, you are entirely right. However, I am currently only intending to learn ROS, and I have no restraints regarding versions etc., so I think I will try out Jade at this point.